# How to redirect to facebook app after login

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

I try make a app for test. (Use host heroku)
This is simple code. It use show username.

```
<?php
require_once("src/facebook.php");
require_once("src/base_facebook.php");
   $config = array(
      'appId' => '#my_app_id',
      'secret' => '#serect code',
      'fileUpload' => false, // optional
      'allowSignedRequest' => false
  ); 
$params = array(
   'redirect_uri' => 'My_apps_on_facebook_where_in_fanpage' 
//example: https://www.facebook.com/test_fanpage/app_id
    );
    $facebook=new Facebook($config);
    $user_id=$facebook->getUser(); // get user id
        if($user_id==true) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $login_url. "'</script>"); 
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $login_url. "'</script>"); 

    }
?>
```

I tested it. After login with oauth dialog. The page will be redirect to My_apps_on_facebook_where_in_fanpage but it loops forever. I want to redirect to my apps on fanpage one times and show name of user. How i can fix it. Thanks

Comment: i added app in my fanpage, and i want to redirect to it

Comment: I use apps.facebook url but it still be looping redirect

Comment: @SyedQarib Nope, you're wrong it can be anything! Your website, a fan page